# How to initialise data structure once in python loop

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I am trying to build up a data structure from a CSV file. The CSV file contents are below.

```
‘Windows 8’,10.1.1.1,’Windows 8 Server’,’SiteA’
‘Windows 8’,10.2.2.2,’Windows 8 Server’,’SiteB’
‘Cisco Router,’172.16.1.1’,’Cisco Router 881’,’SiteA’
‘Cisco Router,’172.16.1.3’,’Cisco Router 881’,’SiteC’
‘Cisco Router,’172.16.1.4’,’Cisco Router 881’,’SiteB’
```

I am trying to group the data by Device Type, then Site and have a list of common ip addresses along with the description.

The problem I am having is I cannot work out to ensure I am only initialising the various parts of the data structure only one.

Below is my code.

```
import csv
import pprint

data = {}

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)


f = open('/Users/marcos/Desktop/vulns/data.csv', 'rt')
try:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
            product = row[0]
            ip = row[1]
            description = row[2]
            site = row[3]
            try:
                data[product][site]['ipaddresses'].append(ip)
                data[product][site]['description'] = description
            except:
                data[product] = {}
                data[product][site] = {}
                data[product][site]['ipaddresses'] = []
                data[product][site]['ipaddresses'].append(ip)
                data[product][site]['description'] = description

finally:
    f.close()

pp.pprint(data)
```

What I am currently getting is the following, which is because my except is always triggering I believe

```
{   '‘Cisco Router': {   '’SiteB’': {   'description': '’Cisco Router     881’',
                                    'ipaddresses': ['’172.16.1.4’']}},
    '‘Windows 8’': {   '’SiteB’': {   'description': '’Windows 8 Server’',
                                  'ipaddresses': ['10.2.2.2']}}}
```

Comment: The usual way to deal with this is to use `defaultdict(dict)` (from `collections`) to automatically initiallze missing keys, or manually check `if my_item not in my_dict: my_dict[my_item] = {}` before adding to the dict (or list, or...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raising an exception is useful in showing what is actually wrong. When I did this I saw KeyErrors, so I used this approach:

```
try:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        product = row[0]
        ip = row[1]
        description = row[2]
        site = row[3]
        try:
            if product not in data:
                data[product] = {}
            if site not in data[product]:
                data[product][site] = {}
            if 'description' not in data[product][site]:
                data[product][site]['description'] = description
            if 'ipaddresses' not in data[product][site]:
                data[product][site]['ipaddresses'] = []
            data[product][site]['ipaddresses'].append(ip)
            data[product][site]['description'] = description
        except Exception, e:
            raise

finally:
    f.close()

pp.pprint(data)
```

Notice that I am creating any keys, lists, or dicts that are needed before trying to work with them. 
This gives me the following output:

```
{   'Cisco Router': {   'SiteA': {   'description': 'Cisco Router 881',
                                     'ipaddresses': ['172.16.1.1']},
                        'SiteB': {   'description': 'Cisco Router 881',
                                     'ipaddresses': ['172.16.1.4']},
                        'SiteC': {   'description': 'Cisco Router 881',
                                     'ipaddresses': ['172.16.1.3']}},
    'Windows 8': {   'SiteA': {   'description': 'Windows 8 Server',
                                  'ipaddresses': ['10.1.1.1']},
                     'SiteB': {   'description': 'Windows 8 Server',
                                  'ipaddresses': ['10.2.2.2']}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using the `.setdefault` method. When used in a loop it does exactly what you're asking for: It initialises the value if the key does not exist, otherwise it returns the stored value.
I personally like it but I can see how others don't because it makes nested lookups a bit harder to read. It's a matter of taste:

```
reader = """
‘Windows 8’,10.1.1.1,’Windows 8 Server’,’SiteA’
‘Windows 8’,10.2.2.2,’Windows 8 Server’,’SiteB’
‘Cisco Router,’172.16.1.1’,’Cisco Router 881’,’SiteA’
‘Cisco Router,’172.16.1.3’,’Cisco Router 881’,’SiteC’
‘Cisco Router,’172.16.1.4’,’Cisco Router 881’,’SiteB’
"""

reader = [line.split(',') for line in reader.replace("'", '').strip().split('\n')]

data = {}
for row in reader:
    product, ip, description, site = row[:4]
    site_data = data.setdefault(product, {}).setdefault(site, {})
    site_data.setdefault('ipaddresses', []).append(ip)
    site_data['description'] = description

import pprint
pprint.pprint(data)
```

Prints:

```
{'‘Cisco Router': {'’SiteA’': {'description': '’Cisco Router 881’',
                               'ipaddresses': ['’172.16.1.1’']},
                   '’SiteB’': {'description': '’Cisco Router 881’',
                               'ipaddresses': ['’172.16.1.4’']},
                   '’SiteC’': {'description': '’Cisco Router 881’',
                               'ipaddresses': ['’172.16.1.3’']}},
 '‘Windows 8’': {'’SiteA’': {'description': '’Windows 8 Server’',
                             'ipaddresses': ['10.1.1.1']},
                 '’SiteB’': {'description': '’Windows 8 Server’',
                             'ipaddresses': ['10.2.2.2']}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a useful time to use pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

data_ = pd.read_csv('path-to-data.csv')
data_.columns = ['product', 'ip', 'description', 'site']

# Create a 'grouped' dataset object   
grouped = df.groupby(['product', 'site', 'ip'])

# Create a dataset with a list of unique 'description' values, 
# grouped by columns above
   unique_desc_by_group = grouped['description'].aggregate(lambda x: tuple(x))

print(unique_desc_by_group)
```

[image]